# Click sound not playing android onClick

Tags: android, audio

I have this:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
```

in my XML. And in my class I have:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        increment(button, key, this);
    }
```

However the CLICK sound is still not working

Comment: are the touch sounds enabled in the device settings?

Comment: @Lino how do I check that? And is there a workaround of enabling it WITHOUT going into device settings?

Comment: it should be under Settings/Sound/Touch sounds or similar. Didn't know if there exists a workaround

Comment: @Lino I can't find the setting, but I don't want to have someone enable it anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According with Android developer page the method PlaySoundEffect

> The sound effect will only be played if sound effects are enabled by the user, and isSoundEffectsEnabled() is true.

So in the Settings-> Sounds the sound effects must be activated.

Try

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),<yoursound> );
mp.start();
```

instead.
This sound will play always if audio (for media) is turned on

Comment: I've searched the internet everywhere but couldn't find a click sound. Can you link me to one?

Comment: Here http://soundjax.com/click-1.html some pages of click sounds.
You put your sound on raw directory of your project and use R.raw.nameofsound of second parameter of create() method of MediaPlayer